# Geocoding non-addresses: Geopy

Tags: python, google-maps, geopy

Using geopy to geocode alcohol outlets in NZ.

The problem I have is that some places do not have street addresses but are places in Google Maps. For example, plugging:

```
Furneaux Lodge, Endeavour Inlet, Queen Charlotte Sound, Marlborough 7250
```

into Google Maps via the browser GUI gives me

[image]
However, using that in Geopy I get a GQueryError saying this geographic location does not exist.

Here is the code for geocoding:

```
def GeoCode(address):
    g=geocoders.Google(domain="maps.google.co.nz") 
    geoloc = g.geocode(address, exactly_one=False)
    place, (lat, lng) = geoloc[0]
    GeoOut = []
    GeoOut.extend([place, lat, lng])
    return GeoOut

GeoCode("Furneaux Lodge, Endeavour Inlet, Queen Charlotte Sound, Marlboroguh 7250")
```

Meanwhile, I notice that "Eiffel Tower" works fine. Is there away to solve this and can someone explain the difference between The Eiffel Tower and Furneaux Lodge within Google 'locations'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a Google Maps API limitation. [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) however seems to know about `Furneaux Lodge`, so you can use it as a fallback to Google Maps if the Google Maps query doesn't return an answer:

```
>>> from geopy import geocoders
>>> gn = geocoders.GeoNames()  
>>> place, (lat, lng) = gn.geocode('Furneaux Lodge')
>>> print('{}: {:.5f}, {:.5f}'.format(place, lat, lng))
Furneaux Lodge, F4, NZ: -41.08826, 174.18019
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro. That sounds like a logical idea.